# How to generate pdf from angular2

Tags: angular, pdf-generation, jspdf

My pdf file appears like this:

[image: Pdf appears like this]

I have a screen on click of print, whole screen must be converted to pdf format.
I tried to do like this, but it is splitting the page, i am not able to get the whole screen properly. 
Please help.

Ts:

```
generateToPdf() {
let pdf = new jsPDF('p','pt','a4');
pdf.setFontSize(50); 
pdf.canvas.height = 72 * 11;
pdf.canvas.width = 72 * 7;
    pdf.addHTML(this.el.nativeElement, 0, 0, () => {
        pdf.save("test.pdf");
    });
}
```

Stackblitz Link: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-avdqfz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: How can you accommodate the Content that exceeds to multiple page in single page?

Comment: @SureshKumarAriya Thanks for response, i am able to get the pdf of whole page but this is not clear, its with full of blur data

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass an option parameter to enable page splitting,

```
 {
  pagesplit: true
 }
```

Just pass this, for e.g.-

```
generateToPdf() {
    let pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.addHTML(this.el.nativeElement, 0, 0,{pagesplit: true}, () => {
        pdf.save("test.pdf");
    });
}
```

Comment: this will split my page

Comment: i dont want to split, what ever it is coming is fine but it is blur

Comment: @Bhrungarajni Try reducing the width of the page.